# Как достучаться до свойств атрибута?

Tags: c#

У меня есть `Type` атрибута. Я разбираю `Assembly` по типам, которые имеют нужный атрибут.

```
types = ass.GetTypes().Where(t => t.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == utilTypes[1]));
```

То есть получаю список типов. Мне нужно, перебирая этот список, достать свойства атрибута. Ну например вот из этого

```
[MyAttribute("Hello")]
class MyClass{}
```

мне нужно достать свойство *Prop1*, которое равно *"Hello"*. Как это сделать? Чего то уже совсем запутался в этих рефлекциях :(

**UPD1**

Забыл сказать. У меня нет прямого доступа к типу атрибута. То есть я не могу сделать так

```
foreach (var type in types)
{
    var MyAttr = (MyAttributeAttribute)type.GetCustomAttribute(utilTypes[0].GetType())
}
```

Потому что этот самый тип атрибута `MyAttributeAttribute` я имею только в текстовом виде. А значит мне нужно каким то образом достать из него свойство, к которому я не имею прямой доступ

Comment: Может dynamic попробовать? Мне проблематично экспериментировать. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий подход.
Пусть тип экземпляра класса `MyClass` лежит в переменной `type`. То есть:

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
```

Или в вашем случае:

```
Type type = types[i];
```

Тогда следующий код:

```
var attr = type.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType == utilTypes[0]);
if (attr != null)
{
    var attrType = attr.AttributeType;
    var propInfo = attrType.GetProperty("Prop1", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    Console.WriteLine(propInfo.GetValue(mcType.GetCustomAttribute(attrType)));
}
```

Выведет:

> Hello

---

Вот, оформил в виде метода:

```
public static object GetAttributeProperty(Type classType, Type attributeType, string propertyName)
{
    var propInfo = attributeType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    return propInfo.GetValue(classType.GetCustomAttribute(attributeType));
}
```

Comment: Смысл ясен, но я таки уже сделал через dynamic. Если в дальнейшем это вызовет проблемы, воспользуюсь предложенным вами способом.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx) у класса `Type`
Например так

```
foreach (var type in types)
{
   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(<Имя свойства>, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
   if(propertyInfo != null)
   {
       // свойство с таким именем найдено
   }
}
```

Найдя свойство, из структуры [System.Reflection.PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) можно получить и значение свойства, и тип... дело техники уже

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    class MyAttributeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; private set; }
        public MyAttributeAttribute(string myProp) { MyProperty = myProp; }
    }

    [MyAttribute("Hello")]
    class TestClass { }

    static void Main()
    {
        Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var types = ass.GetTypes().Where(t => t.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "MyAttributeAttribute"));

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var ma = type.GetCustomAttributes().FirstOrDefault((a) => { return a.GetType().Name == "MyAttributeAttribute"; });
            if (ma == null)
                continue;

            var prop = ma.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty");
            if (prop == null)
                continue;

            string str = prop.GetValue(ma).ToString(); // --> Hello
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если параметр обязательный - то проще всего получить его значение вот так:

```
var attr = type.CustomAttributes.Single(a => a.AttributeType.FullName == "My.Namespace.MyAttribute");
Console.WriteLine(attr.ConstructorArguments[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

А как же статическая типизация? Добавьте интерфейс, который реализует необходимое вам свойство, ищите типы, которые его имплементируют, инстанциируйте их экземпляры и приведите к интерфейсу.

Comment: Не мой это тип. Дергаю его со сторонней сборки по имени.

Comment: Из вопроса это не было очевидно. Тем не менее, не забывайте, что считается, что получать данные рефлексией - примерно в 100 раз медленней, чем через обычный вызов.